# Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Context, Configuration>()); Error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration

Well the error I am getting is actually a compiler error which is

> CS0311: there is no implicit reference conversion from...

I enabled migrations from package manager

```
 public class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<PMDBContext>
 {
     public Configuration()
     {
         AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
         AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
         ContextKey = "Context.DB.Context";
     }

     protected override void Seed(PMWeb.Models.PMDBContext context)
     {
         //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.
         //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
         //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
         //
         //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
         //      p => p.FullName,
         //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
         //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
         //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
         //    );
         //
     }
 }
```

And this statement:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DbContext, Configuration>());
```

generates the following error:

> Error    4   The type 'PMWeb.Migrations.Configuration' cannot be used as type parameter 'TMigrationsConfiguration' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'PMWeb.Migrations.Configuration' to 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration'. f:\dropbox\partymag\pmweb\models\pmdbcontext.cs 52  83  PMWeb

BTW, this was working fine before, I do not know what changed.

Comment: "working fine before" in a different project or this particular project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<PMDBContext, Configuration>());
```

I was supposed to give my context not the base context class. Silly me. :)

Comment: Please, correct your answer. The code line is still wrong: you are using the DbContext class.

Comment: yeah, it is been so long. I fixed it, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @EgeAydın where are you adding the `Database.SetInitializer` command?

Comment: Sorry, it is been a long time. But If I don't remember it wrong, i think it was inside the DBContext class.